# Azure Unable to upgrade the deployment

Tags: azure, azure-deployment

I try to deploy my CloudProviders and I ger this error

> Unable to upgrade the deployment. The requested VM size
>   'Standard_D1_v2' may not be available in the resources supporting the
>   existing deployment. Please try again later, try with a different VM
>   size or smaller number of role instances, or create a deployment under
>   an empty hosted service with a new affinity group or no affinity group
>   binding.

I deleted and recreated the CloudService but not solved my error.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, VM deployment may occasionally fail due to various reasons. I'd recommend opening a support ticket.

Find more details below:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/allocation-failure
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/allocation-failure-and-remediation/